# Is pumpkin harmful to cats?

Tags: cats, health, chewing

After carving a jack-o-lantern, one of my cats decided that he liked the texture of pumpkin.  Is it okay for him to be chewing on the pumpkin, or do I need to find a place for it out of his reach?

*Note: I don't think he's eating any of it, just chewing.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://cats.about.com/od/catsafety/a/SafeHalloween.htm

Pumpkin itself isn't toxic, but if the pumpkin's been sitting out, it could harbor germs that will make your animal sick.  Also, if the cat does eat the pumpkin, pumpkin contains fiber that could act as a laxative (though this is a possible benefit if your cat is constipated).  In conclusion, I wouldn't worry too much if your cat does get at it, but I would still make some effort to try to keep your jack-o-lanterns away from the cat.