# Pumpkin spice for cats, is it good for them?

Tags: cats, diet, safety, eating

Would pumpkin spice be good to add to cat food or not? If not why not?

Comment: Why are you considering this?

Comment: I just thought that it might make a good addition to cat food primarily.@JamesJenkins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, **NO**. Pumpkin spice is **not good** for Cats, Dogs or Rabbits, or probably any pet.

Plain Pumpkin is fine for most any pet.  It can be helpful in digestion and as long as it not spoiled is [fine for cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6674/)

Pumpkin Spice on the other hand can contain any number of [additives (spices) which can be toxic.](http://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/uncategorized/pumpkin-spice-naughty-nice/)

There is pumpkin specifically canned for pets, but you can also buy canned pumpkin at most grocery stores. Purchasing plain pumpkin, is fine, read the lable to verify there are not additives, but **NEVER BUY PUMPKIN PIE FILLING** it has the spices that can harm (or kill) your pet.